# for loop in Parallel.ForEach is not completing

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, parallel.foreach

I wrote this code:

```
private async Task<ConcurrentBag<IrfRecord>> ProcessData(string sourceFileContent)
{
    var irfs = new ConcurrentBag<IrfRecord>();
    var indexArr = new[]
    {
        3, 13, 23, 25, 35, 45, 55, 56, 59,
        69, 74, 94, 96, 97, 122, 137, 152, 162, 172, 182, 192, 202, 212, 213, 215, 217
    };
    var splittedContent = sourceFileContent.Split(new []{ Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        IrfRecord irf;
        Parallel.ForEach(splittedContent, (lne,loopState) =>
        {
            if (lne.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }                   
            try
            {
                irf = new IrfRecord()
                {
                    Key = lne.Substring(3, 10) + "-" + lne.Substring(45, 10),
                    Body = SplitAt(lne, indexArr).Select((item, idx) => new IrfRecordProperty
                    {
                        Value = item
                    }).ToList()
                };

                for (var i = 0; i < irf.Body.Count -1; i++)
                {
                    irf.Body[i].Settings = irf.Body[i].GetValue(i);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

            irfs.Add(irf);
        });
    });
    return irfs;
}
```

I'm using it from a different method like:

```
var sourceObjects = ProcessData(await sourceFileRead);
var outboundObjects = ProcessData(await outboundFileRead);
await Task.WhenAll(sourceObjects, outboundObjects);
```

However, I keep getting NullPointerExceptions on `irf.Body[i].Settings` later on in the code, means in the inside loop doesn't finish it's job for some reason. the inside loop is using the `GetValue` method, that will never return null.

I thought maybe i'm continuing while the Task didn't finish, but I have `Task.WhenAll` as you can see on the second code block. Note that when i'm debugging, 99% of my `Body[i].Settings` is populated as expected.

I really don't get it, isn't my inside for loop should just complete normally If the outer Parallel foreach finished successfuly ??

Comment: `irf` variable is shared between parallel tasks. Move it inside the `Parallel.ForEach` body.

Comment: I'll try it, but the parallel loop is going over about 100,000, wouldn't it kill the memory ? creating new objects ?

Comment: No. You are already creating new objects. But *storing* them in a shared temp variable, thus interfering with other parallel tasks.

Comment: It's running for more than 13 minutes (stopped it),.. When irf was outside, it finished in a second and populated irfs with all the 100,000 items,.

Comment: It finished in a second because your code was fundamentally broken.

Comment: I assume.. I'll try to keep trying to find the issue there.. it's hard to debug.. :(